# I Can't interact with files and applications after first login

Tags: 12.04, login

Every time I restart my computer and login into my ubuntu account for the first time, I can't click on anything besides the bar on the left.

I can start Firefox from there, but I am not able to click on the new tab button etc.

Same will all other apps. I can start the Terminal via the keyboard, but I can't move it around.

I have to logout via the keyboard and login again. Usually everything works fine now. Just waiting doesn't help.

The only obvious change I made to Ubuntu was to move the **/home** directory.

Comment: you move /home to where?!

Comment: Basically just this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Are you essentially saying that your mouse/touchpad doesn't work?  If so, then that's what you have to address.  If it's a touchpad, then, most probably, it's a Synaptics touchpad and you can use synclient from a terminal to view and adjust its settings.  Once we know what your pointing device (and computer make and model) is, there are several command line utilities like lspci and lsusb that will give us more information as to what the problem might be.